# Android play again after stoping mediaplayer don't wok

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

in my simple player i have play, and stop buttons and play and pause media player work fine, now after click on stop and play again, media player don't work and i'm not sure whats problem to resolve that

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    playMonthLesson();

    ...
}

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public void playMonthLesson() {
    try {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(CoreApplication.MEDIAFOLDER + "/" + lesson.getFilename());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        lesson_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        int totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

        // set Progress bar values
        lesson_progress_bar.setProgress(curretLessonProgress);
        lesson_progress_bar.setMax(100);

        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@OnClick(R.id.lesson_play)
public void lesson_play(View view) {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
        playMonthLesson();
    } else if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            // Changing button image to play button
            lesson_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        }
    } else {
        // Resume song
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            // Changing button image to pause button
            lesson_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        }
    }
}

@OnClick(R.id.lesson_stop)
public void setLesson_stop(View view) {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        lesson_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        lesson_progress_bar.setProgress(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you make sure if onCreateView is not called again and agin after completion? try to use debugger or logger to find out. You can use that for several steps in your code and find where it is repeating itself

Answer (score 1):

According to the `MediaPlayer` life cycle, which you can view in the [Android API guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), I think that you have to call `reset()` instead of `stop()`, and after that prepare again the media player (use only one) to play the sound from the beginning. Take also into account that the sound may have finished. So I would also recommend to implement `setOnCompletionListener()` to make sure that if you try to play again the sound it doesn't fail.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you stop mediaplayer and click on play again your call will go to `mediaplayer.play()` as mediaplayer is not null.

You will have to null the mediaPlayer on stop method. Now, once you stop mediaplayer and again click on play it will call `playMonthLesson();`

```html
@OnClick(R.id.lesson_stop)
public void setLesson_stop(View view) {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer = null;
        lesson_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        lesson_progress_bar.setProgress(0);
    }
}
```

change this code too,

```html
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public void playMonthLesson() {
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(CoreApplication.MEDIAFOLDER + "/" + lesson.getFilename());
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){

        @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
               mp.start();
               lesson_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
               int totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();  
        // set Progress bar values
        lesson_progress_bar.setProgress(curretLessonProgress);
        lesson_progress_bar.setMax(100);

        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but media don't play again